# How to add div dynamically inside a div by class - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want dynamically add **info** div into every dynamic class.

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
   <div class='dynamic'></div>
   <div class='dynamic'></div>
   <div class='dynamic'></div>
   <div class='dynamic'></div>
</div>
```

I want like this.

```
<div id='container'>
   <div class='dynamic'><div class="info">info</div></div>
   <div class='dynamic'><div class="info">info</div></div>
   <div class='dynamic'><div class="info">info</div></div>
   <div class='dynamic'><div class="info">info</div></div>
</div>
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4cncLor7/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an info div into every class using jQuery, simply use:

```
$( ".dynamic" ).append( "<div class='info'>info</div>" );
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cncLor7/5/) demonstrates it.

If you want to continually check for `.dynamic` classes, you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function(){
    $( ".dynamic" ).append( "<div class='info'>info</div>" );
}, 1000));
```

In the above case, you are checking for `.dynamic` classes every 1000ms (1 second).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question was phrased "I want dynamically add info div into every dynamic class.".  I assumed perhaps the user would dynamically add divs via some user action, and want those divs to contain the info divs.  So I provided an option/example for if its any useful.

Comment: Thanks @gehleh, and how can i add .info as parent to some div.

Comment: @GoldPearl do you mean at the beginning of your `dynamic` div before other content already inside `dynamic`? If so see my answer with the solution.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, a way to add .info as a parent would be to insert the child content..For this you can use .append() as shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).  `$( ".info" ).append( "<div class='child'>Child</div>" );`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`$.wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) method

```js
$(".dynamic").wrapInner('<div class="info">info</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="dynamic"></div>
  <div class="dynamic"></div>
  <div class="dynamic"></div>
  <div class="dynamic"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('.dynamic').append($('<div/>', { class: 'info' }).html('info'));
```

Update your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cncLor7/2/

If your `.dynamic` div already contains content and you want to at the `.info` div at the beginning use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$('.dynamic').prepend($('<div/>', { class: 'info' }).html('info'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated it. Please check and give me feedback.
http://jsfiddle.net/4cncLor7/4/

```
jQuery('.dynamic').html('<div class="info">info</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.dynamic').each(function() {
   var newDiv = $('div');
   newDiv.addClass('info');
   newDiv.html('info');

   //inject the new div
   $(this).append(newDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this  code :   [Example](http://codepen.io/vicmathur/pen/ZOApva?editors=0001)

Javascript:

```
var vof=$("#box1").val();
//$(".result-box").text(vof);
var e = $('<div class="result-box">'+vof+'</div>');
$('#box').append(e);
```

HTML :

```
<div id="box">
<!--<div class="result-box" id="rbx"></div>-->
</div>
```

here i am creating dynamic div so that every time button is clicked it create new div and you can add attribute id to them separately